# QBResponseException e gives me Unauthorized error for login , register and social login

Tags: android, quickblox

Why QBResponseException e gives me Unauthorized error ?

I have my credentials sidd@gmail.com/12345678 that is working fine here in India and i am also able to register new user on your server from India , But when i am sending application to my client**(USA(Califirnia (CA)))** for review the App do not works , It always gives Quickblox Unauthorized error when ever he tried to register new User or try to login with existing user.

Let me know what is causing this ?

Code i am using :-

**FaceBook Login** :-

```
public void qbFbAPiCall(final Context mContext) {
        QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.FACEBOOK, appPreferences.getPrefrenceString("fbTokken"), null).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle args) {
                appPreferences.setPrefrenceBoolean(Constant.FB_LOGIN, true);
                QBAuth.createSession(qbUser);
                qbUser.setEmail(appPreferences.getPrefrenceString(Constant.FB_USER_EMAIL));
                qbUser.setFullName(appPreferences.getPrefrenceString(Constant.USERNAME));
                qbUser.setPhone(verifyNumber);
                try {
                    qbUser.setPassword(BaseService.getBaseService().getToken());
                } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                fbQbLogin(qbUser);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                AppUtils.dismissProgressDialog();
                AsyncProgressDialog.userErrorDialog(((Activity) mContext), mContext.getString(R.string.error), mContext.getString(R.string.fb_exist), Constant.ALERT);
            }
        });

    }
```

**Registering Process** :-

```
public void qbRegisterApiCall() {
    QBUser qbUser = new QBUser();
    qbUser.setFullName(name);
    qbUser.setLogin(name);
    qbUser.setPassword(userPassword);
    qbUser.setEmail(userEmail);
    QBUsers.signUp(qbUser).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle bundle) {
            qbLoginAPiCall(userEmail, userPassword);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            AppUtils.dismissProgressDialog();
            AsyncProgressDialog.userErrorDialog(((Activity) mContext), mContext.getString(R.string.sorry), "Quickblox" + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Constant.ALERT);
        }
    });
}

public void qbLoginAPiCall(String email, String password) {
    final QBUser qbUser = new QBUser();
    qbUser.setPassword(password);
    qbUser.setEmail(email);
    login(qbUser, password);
}

private void login(final QBUser user, String password) {
    QBUsers.signIn(user).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle bundle) {
            user.setPassword(password);
            ChatHelper.getInstance().login(user, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result, Bundle bundle) {
                    SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance().saveQbUser(user);
                    appPreferences.setPrefrenceString(Constant.USER_QB_ID, String.valueOf(user.getId()));
                    AppUtils.dismissProgressDialog();
                    startUpDialog = true;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    ((Activity) mContext).finishAffinity();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                    AppUtils.dismissProgressDialog();
                    AsyncProgressDialog.userErrorDialog(((Activity) mContext), mContext.getString(R.string.error), "Quickblox" + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Constant.ALERT);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            AppUtils.dismissProgressDialog();
            AsyncProgressDialog.userErrorDialog(((Activity) mContext), mContext.getString(R.string.error), "Quickblox" + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Constant.ALERT);

        }
    });
}
```

**Login Process** :-

```
public void qbLoginAPiCall() {
    QBUser qbUser = new QBUser();
    if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(activityLoginBinding.getLoginViewModel().email.get().trim()).matches()) {
        qbUser.setEmail(activityLoginBinding.getLoginViewModel().email.get().trim());
    } else {
        qbUser.setLogin(activityLoginBinding.getLoginViewModel().email.get().trim());
    }
    qbUser.setPassword(activityLoginBinding.getLoginViewModel().password.get().trim());
    login(qbUser);
}

private void login(QBUser user) {

    QBUsers.signIn(user).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle bundle) {
            user.setPassword(activityLoginBinding.getLoginViewModel().password.get().trim());
            ChatHelper.getInstance().login(user, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.i("Success chatService : ", " ");
                    SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance().saveQbUser(user);
                    appPreferences.setPrefrenceBoolean(Constant.RESTORE_CHAT, false);
                    appPreferences.setPrefrenceString(Constant.USER_QB_ID, String.valueOf(user.getId()));
                    appPreferences.setPrefrenceString(Constant.USERNAME, user.getFullName());
                    AppUtils.dismissProgressDialog();
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class));
                    ((Activity) mContext).finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                    appPreferences.setPrefrenceBoolean(Constant.FB_LOGIN, false);
                    AppUtils.dismissProgressDialog();
                    AsyncProgressDialog.userErrorDialog(((Activity) mContext), mContext.getString(R.string.error), "Quickblox" + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Constant.ALERT);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            appPreferences.setPrefrenceBoolean(Constant.FB_LOGIN, false);
            AppUtils.dismissProgressDialog();
            AsyncProgressDialog.userErrorDialog(((Activity) mContext), mContext.getString(R.string.error), "Quickblox" + " " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Constant.ALERT);
        }
    });
}
```

**Please let me know the case . All Above methods are working here at my end (India) but for USA it's giving me Unauthorized Error**.

**Client is  not able to login in app using his Facebook account/Register new account / pre-existing credentials**

Thanks

Comment: Add qbUser.setLogin(name) during login. As you are using both Name and  email for authentication. Also check the console if that social id is already register there. Remove the user and then check again .

Comment: @ADM , Thanks for your answer but it won't put any effect to my code , I am able to login with my credentials here , but when i am sending that to my client he is getting QB unauthorized error , same when he tries to create new account but every functionality is working here with me in India , I am confused that how it can be , it's really a strange problem i am encountering.

Comment: There is the same [issue](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/483) on git. So wait for Contributors reply. As this seems to me little awkward problem .